# How can I use Perl to extract multiple lines here?

Tags: regex, perl

I'm having some trouble sorting through and extracting multiple lines of text. Here's my code:

```
my $searched = $doc->content;
    if($searched =~ /MODIFIED files in Task $_[1] : (.*?) The/gs){
        print $1,"\n";
        $Modified = $1;

    }
    if($searched =~ m/COMPILED in Task $_[1] : (.*?) The/ms){
        $Compiled = $1;

    }
    if($searched =~ m/DELETED in Task $_[1] : (.*?) Comments/ms){
        $Deleted = $1;

    }
```

Here's is a example of the text file:

> ```
> The following are the MODIFIED files in Task 50104 :
>
> **Directory                Filename                Version
> ---------                --------                -------
> Something                Something                .....
> ......                   ......                   .....
> .......                  ........                 .....**
>
> The following are the files to be COMPILED in Task 50104 :
>
> **Directory                Filename
> ---------                --------
> .........               .........**
>
>
> The following are the files to be DELETED in Task 50104 :
>
> **Directory                Filename
> ---------                --------**
>
> Comments:
>  Blah blah.......
> ```

Where the text in between the ** is what I want to extract. Sorry about the poor formatting

Comment: Is the empty line above `The following are...` guaranteed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure that your text contains spaces around `:` and before The/Comments (in fact, it seems to me that `:` is followed by newline, and `The` is preceded by newline, not space); instead of using:

```
if($searched =~ /MODIFIED files in Task $_[1] : (.*?) The/gs){
```

try using:

```
if($searched =~ /MODIFIED files in Task $_[1] :(.*?)The/gs){
```

I also don't think you need the /g or /m switch...

If this does not work, I would suggest refining your regex in steps, i.e., first ensure that `/MODIFIED files in Task $_[1] :` matches up to the `:` then add the rest.

Answer (score 1):

[Flip-flop operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators) to the rescue!

The flip-flop operator has two sides, left and right. Once the left side evaluates to true, the flip-flop stays true until the right side evaluates to true.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $searched = $doc->content;

my %info;  #< Store in a hash >

open my $string, '<', \$searched or die $!;

{
    my ( $type, $content );

    while ( <$string> ) {  # Process $searched line-by-line

        if ( /(MODIFIED|COMPILED|DELETED)/ ) {

            $type = $1;
        }

        $content .= $_, next if /^Directory/ .. /^\s*$/ ;

        $content =~ s{\s+$}{}; # Don't need that trailing whitespace

        if ( defined $type && defined $content ) {

            $info{$type} = $content;  # Or push @{ $info{$type} }, $content;
            undef $type;
            undef $content;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's a little old, but I'm a fan of this article as a way of getting to know the flip flop (`..`) operator: http://www.perl.com/pub/2004/06/18/variables.html

Comment: `push`ing strings onto a `@content` and then processing as a list or joining is cheaper than `.=`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick hack (untested). Instead of reading the entire file into a string, use it in line-by-line mode:

`$ script.pl inputfile.txt`

```
my %data;
my $header;
while (<>) {
    next if /^\s*$/; # skip empty lines
    if (/^The following are /) { # header line
        if (/(MODIFIED|COMPILED|DELETED)/) {
            $header = $1;
        } else { die "Bad header: $_" }
    } else { # data line
        die "Header expected" unless (defined $header);
        $data{$header} .= $_;
    }
}
```